# Display messages from rosbag

Tags: c++, rosbag, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
I want to display the data in some messages from different rosbags. I don know what kind of messages each rosbag has but I want to be able to check that. And then be able to choose which message to display in a graph. My plan is to choose message from a GUI which I will design in QT. But I have problem with reading the data from rosbags messages without knowing exactly what every rosbag contains. Does anyone know how to approach this? (And I am new to ros (that you might have guessed) so please keep it simple).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269587/display-messages-from-rosbag/) by [roger](https://answers.ros.org/users/31699/roger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-25**:
What you describe sounds very much like [rqt_bag](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_bag), [rqt_multiplot](https://github.com/ethz-asl/rqt_multiplot_plugin) and [plotjuggler](https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler). Perhaps you could look at those and see how they do it - if you cannot use those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rqt_bag](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_bag) and [rqt_plot](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_plot) function almost exactly as your proposed solution. [Here](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostics/Tutorials/Viewing%20Logged%20Diagnostics%20in%20rqt_bag) is a simple tutorial to view bag files and [rqt_plot](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_plot) has a similar tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [KwanFace](https://answers.ros.org/users/31704/kwanface/) with karma: 26 on 2017-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0